# search somebody from contacts with the numpads

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-4, phone-app

My old phone Motorola Defy had the option by calling to search for a contact just typing a number. Not sure how that feature is called but I'll give an example:

If I want to call "Alex" i need to press 2(**a** bc) 5(jk **l**) 3(d **e** f) 9(w **x** yz) and I press the call button.

Now I got the Nexus 4 and there is not such a feature, which is really annoying. Is there a custom dialer that support this feature? Or is it possible to enable it from somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with the stock dialer. There are a number of apps that you can install that do support this. Search the play store for 't9 dialer' (or click [here](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=t9%20dialer&c=apps)). Pick one that you like the look of :)